# μονογενῆ, should John 3:16 be translated with "one-of-a-kind" or "only begotten"?

Tags: greek, john, jesus, hebrew-bible, christology

> John 3:16, “For God so loved the world that he gave his only (**μονογενῆ**) Son, so that everyone who believes in him may not perish but may have eternal life."

My question resides in the greek term μονογενῆ often translated a "only" or "only begotten" and which seems to be a significant part of Christian theology.  This seems to indicate that Jesus is God's ONLY child.

I am not understanding how this translation can square with the John concept that we can also be children of God (τέκνα Θεοῦ) as in John 1:12 and elsewhere in the Johannine letters.  This concept also appears in Philippians and Romans, but not anywhere else in the new testament.

Important to the New Testament (God sacrifices his son), this is also related to the child sacrifice narratives of Isaac (Genesis 22) and Jephthah's daughter (Judges 11).  It seems to be related to the Hebrew word *yachid* (יְחִֽידְךָ֤).  In Gen 22:2, *yachid* is used to describe Isaac, and is translated as αγαπητόν (the one you love), and in Judges *yachid* is directly translated as μονογενής.  But in Judges, it follows on saying that she was his μονογενής daughter, AND he had no other daughters or sons.  The idea of μονογενής and "no other children" seem to be two separate and distinct properties.  The greek does not use the term for "for/because," but the conjunction "and/but."

μονογενῆ seems to be explicitly μονο-γενῆ which means "one" (mono) and "kind" (genus - as in species taxonomy).  Furthermore, Isaac was clearly not an only child to Abraham.  Abraham was also the father of Ishmael.

This seems to be a crucial point to Christian theology.  Was Jesus a "one of a kind" child of God or "only begotten?"  If he is only begotten, then how can we also be children of God?  Psalm 2 seems to indicate (though not naming) that King David is God's annointed (Mesiah) and also his begotten child (though I assume many will take this as a prophecy of Jesus).

But then there are the explicit references to the children (or sons) of God in Genesis 6:2, and in Job 1:6 and 2:1, בְּנֵ֣י הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים, "Children of God," (Greek: υιοί του θεού)  Here it is clearly plural and in Job, this menagerie includes Satan.

In Exodus 4:22, God instructs Moses to tell Pharaoh that Israel is God's firstborn son...  I get that there is likely a reference to the "people of Israel" here, but perhaps he is referring to Jacob/Israel and thus to his children?  The name "Ramses" means "child of Ra" (ra-mses), so we see here a contrast and conflict to children of the egyptian God and the god of Moses.  It's interesting that Moses' name has the same root as ramses (MSS), but the place for the god name (ra-mss) is empty, indicating the invisible God of Moses perhaps.

Question:
How can μονογενῆ be translated as "only begotten" or "only" son in the context of the old testament reference and along with the concept that we can also be children of God?  Does being a child of God mean that we are each unique and one-of-a-kind?  Given that John 3:16 is the most quoted New Testament verse, isn't this of extreme importance?

Comment: There is division regarding the translation of _monogenes_. This is dealt with on [SE-C](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71904/a-question-regarding-arguments-against-the-nicene-creed) where reference is made to articles by Deny Burke and, particularly, by [Charles Lee Irons](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/lets-go-back-to-only-begotten/). This is not going to be sorted out on BH, but it is good to be aware that there _is_ a controversy. 'Only begotten' refers to the fact that the Son of God is _generated_ (_eternally_) by the Father, in an everlasting relationship.

Comment: [Related, possible Duplicate.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/should-john-118-be-translated-differently)

Comment: @NigelJ Can we analytically cut out the possibility of it meaning "only child" here on BH?  It seems like... given that there are explicit references to the plural "children of God" as I mentioned, as well as the Pauline and Johannine idea that we can be children of god also, that the term "only" child doesn't apply in the typical way that we think of?  Or perhaps it refers to the idea that there are not separate people, but that each child of God is identical to the only child of God.  I am still not clear on what BH means if we can't address such topics.  Also, this is not about John 1:18.

Comment: @NigelJ, perhaps you can clarify why this doesn't belong on BH?  This question checks all the boxes on the BH help page.  It is solidly grounded in an analysis of the biblical text, its translation, and the historical context as well as inter-textual links within the bible.  The link you sent is an analysis of the Nicene Creed, which is clearly a Christian doctrine thing.  The question I am asking sits behind and informs that questions...  That is how I have interpreted BH versus SE-C...  BH is like an analysis of the source code where SE-C is a user manual for the application.

Comment: There is considerable division over the translation of _monogenes_. KJV has 'only begotten' and that is, by some, disputed. The matter is significant. It also includes complex arguments which need extensive treatment. The link I gave sets out the controversy and gives links to two respected academic experts on the subject. The prime reference is John 1:18 (because of the mention of 'the bosom of the Father') not John 3:16. BH is not the place for repeated re-visiting of known controversies.

Comment: This question was recently merged into from https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73090/25589. I think this was a mistake. One questions how Jesus can be an only child at all regardless of which translation. The other questions how monogenes should generally be translated.

Comment: @Austin This question is still focused on John 3:16. And if it was asking how it should be translated in general, well that would both be off-topic, as well as arguably misguided, as all translation needs to take context into account.

Comment: @curiosdanni, thanks. By general I really meant specific to the passage in question which translation is more attentic and reliable.  In contrast this OP is less concerned about choosing between the alternate translations, but how to harmonize what they both imply, which is that Christ is God's only son, with what we know about various sons of God both past, present and future. These seem like very different questions.

Comment: @curiousdanni I see your edits.  FYI, ramses and moses only have similar sounding names because of the structural requirements of Greek male names.  The hebrew of ramses is רעמסס while the hebrew of moses is משה (mosheh).  I heard your comment at seminary too, bit it makes no sense.  Jesus, for example, is not “son of Je”…. In greek male names cannot end with the “ah” sound..  that is feminine like “sophia.”  So mosheh and joshua are mapped over.  This is a late hellenistic translation artifact, not some sort of Egyptian etymology.

Comment: It is significant that we are children of God when we are "in" Christ.  One only begotten/unique Son in whom we may have life.  Also significant is that Ishmael was the product of an attempted "short cut" to accomplish God's promise for him.  The promised seed was never to have come by Hagar.

Answer (score 5):

If *monogenes* (*mono + genes*) really means 'one of a kind', 'special', 'a single example' and so forth, then what has happened to *genes* ?

*Mono* alone means 'one', 'sole', 'single'.

The rejection of *monogenes* meaning 'only begotten' is too complex and too extensive to properly cover all the many convolutions of argument used in the controversy, on a site such as this. Fourteen Professors and Assistant Professors published a book in order to, extensively, demolish all the tributary arguments and to clear the area of specious claims.

The book is called '*Retrieving Eternal Generation*'. I would not normally draw attention to a publication on BH but this time I think it is justified due to the impossibility of reproducing all the data, here in an answer.

My own publication is called '*The Only Begotten Son of God*' and is available, free of charge, [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiZWxtb250cHVibGljYXRpb25zfGd4OjUzMmE0MGQxZTExYjZiMmY).

What is lost, if *monogenes* be cut in half and the meaning 'sole', 'unique', 'a single kind' and so on, substituted for it - what is lost is the relationship of an eternal generation of Father and Son (in One Holy Spirit).

*One is left with a solitary individual (in humanity) - instead of one united, indivisible God in an eternally generated relationship : Father, Son and Holy Spirit in a perfection of divine love.*

This is not the only example of a controversy being initiated against the eternal relationship of the Father and the Son. And no wonder, for without that relationship one believes in three, unknown, gods. See also the F E Raven & Taylor Senior controversy which split both the Exclusive Brethren and the Strict Baptists in the 19th century using arguments very similar to this division.

Yes, this is a matter of 'theology'. It is so, because that is the *motive* for rejecting 'only begotten' for *monogenes.*

Comment: Fascinating.  Thanks, and +1.  I will take a look at your essay.  I view Jesus as John describes him in John 3:14-16 (which includes monogenes).  Turning our eyes to christ on the cross is an act of obedience.  Christ is as the serpent that Moses raised up in the wilderness.  That serpent was empty.  It was not an idol, but a sign (sēmeion) empty of self and pointing to God.  I think a big problem we have is the evolution of the latin term persona into the english term person.  The former is an empty mask on god.  The latter is a solid idol.  The trinity is three personas, not three persons.

Comment: By using the word 'persona' you seem to be implying that Divine Persons adopted characteristics which do not express their own individuality, thus your way of seeing the matter is not a revelation of what is true of the eternal Deity. I understand that Father, Son and Holy Spirit are revelations of whom God really is. One indivisible God, revealed in three distinct, individuals whose true and eternal relationships are a matter of eternal begetting.

Comment: When analysing the text, what has 'eternal generation' got to do with anything? It has no place and is biblically unfounded. We cannot state that as the *foundation* for any thesis, proof or argument. Including such makes BH a sham.

Comment: Can you be any more specific about why "unique" Son diminishes the doctrine of Christology compared to "only begotten" Son?  If we are all "sons of God" then what does that make Jesus?

Comment: Monogenes literally means one (mono) of a kind (genus - as in taxonomy).  How is there confusion on this other than due to some accumulated doctrinal baggage that is way outside the scope of BH?  Begotten just ain't part of the word.

Answer (score 4):

The operative word here is μονογενής (monogenes) - a word that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious because of the Arian vs Trinitarian controversy.  The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD (and reproduced in the Clementine text).

- 3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus” = unique.
- once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus” = only begotten.
- 5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus” = only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.

The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.

Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132759/discussion-on-answer-by-dottard-john-316-only-begotten-son-only).

Answer (score 3):

The Greek word “MONOGENES” was translated “only begotten” in this verse. μονογενής monogenḗs, mon-og-en-ace'; only-born, i.e. sole:—only (begotten, child), single of its kind.

This word is used only nine times in the New Testament with five of these times referring to Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18; and 1 John 4:9). The other three instances clearly refer to an only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38.). It is translated‘only begotten’ in 6 other places in the NKJ.

Use of this word in describing Jesus as God’s Son further sets apart the virgin birth from all others and underscores, once again, the divinity of Jesus (Mark 1:1, Mark 1:10, Luke 1:27, Luke 1:43, Luke 2:11, and John 1:1).

Comment: Isaac wasn't an only child in Hebrews 11:17 ...he wasn't even the first child of Abraham.

Comment: @Austin You are bordering on another separate question about this, and also entering a theological debate. You are correct about Isaac being the second born, but he is ‘seen’ as the firstborn [of Israel]. And Abraham going to sacrifice his ‘only son’ [when he obviously wasn’t] etc. But that’s outside of the question asked here.

Comment: Well there's no debate here. I think we're both clear on who Isaac is. I think the comment that "the other four instances clearly refer to an only child"  is not accurate. Hebrews 11:17 is more complicated than that. And the complexity should be noted.  I agree, if it hasn't been done before, the subject of Hebrews 11:17 would make a fine question on this stack exchange.

Comment: @Austin Some fair points, and we have reconsidered and edited.

Answer (score 2):

Monogenes is a word of the Greek New Testament that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious because of the Arian vs Trinitarian controversy.  The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD.

- 3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus”, unique.
- once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.
- 5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.

The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.

Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

**Children of God**

Literal adoption was used in both Hebrew (most notably Moses, Ex 1, 2, and Esther) and Roman societies as a means of providing heirs for those who could not have their own, or, providing protection for children deprived of parents by either death or poverty.  It is the latter sense that the New Testament uses the term as a metaphor of a person becoming a “Son of God”.  This idea is drawn from the Old Testament that discusses Israel’s adoption by God (Deut 14:1, 32:6, 18, Jer 31:9, Mal 1:6).

The idea of sinners being adopted as Sons of God occurs infrequently in the NT and only by Paul (Rom 8:15, 23, 9:4, Gal 4:5, Eph 1:5).  However, Jesus appears to unmistakably alludes to adoption in John 3:1-8 and 1:12, 13 where we are able to become children of God.  Rom 1:7, 2 Cor 1:2, Eph 1:2, Gal 1:3, Phil 1:2, 4:20, Col 1:2, 1 Thess 3:11, 2 Thess 1:1, 2, 2:16, 1 Tim 1:2, etc.  This is contradistinction of the Jewish leaders whom Jesus accused of having the Devil as their father, John 8:44.

The metaphor of adoption is extended by the New Testament’s repeated idea of Christ being our brother (Heb 2:11-13, Ps 22:22, Isa 8:17, 18, Matt 12:48, 49, John 20:17, Rom 8:29) following adoption.

Comment: Again, sticking to the Q with very useful information.ty

Answer (score 2):

### Pointless Squabbling

The dispute regarding the rendering "only-begotten" and "only [son]" is completely unnecessary, simply because "only-begotten" and "only son" are *entirely synonymous*. If the Son is the only child, he is the only-begotten, if he is the only-begotten, he is the only son; if one objects to the child really being begotten, he will object to the child really being a child; if one rejects the only-begotten being really begotten, he will reject his being really a child; and the Son's being a child and being begotten are both meant metaphorically.

One is not a child who is not begotten, but a foster child; one who is an only child, is an only-begotten, and vice versa.

Insofar as one is a child, even if used in a metaphorical sense, one is begotten.

> **1 Corinthians 4:15 (DRB)**
> For if you have ten thousand instructors in Christ, yet not many **fathers**. For in Christ Jesus, by the gospel, **I have begotten** you.

'I am your father = I have begotten you. If you are my son, you are my begotten. If my only son, then my only begotten.'

Begotten doesn't imply anything that 'son' or 'child' does not. For both, if one is a metaphor, are metaphors; both, if one is a simile, are similes.

### Hebrew

In Hebrew, only-begotten is *yachid*. *Yachid* simply means *only; alone; one*. It does not say anything about what is the only, what is the one, what is the alone.

But in the context of a child - because all children are begotten - it also means in certain contexts *only-begotten*.

Therefore, whether you interpret *monogenes* as *only-begotten* or *only-child*, you arrive, helplessly, and necessarily, at the same destination.

No one who believes the Son is begotten of God is the son as in offspring of a sexual union, and no one who believes God's is the only Son of God believes there are other sons of God.

Because to Christians, the Son of God is Son because of His having the nature of God. and creatures are God's sons because they are fathered, via being created, by God. Son never means literal sexual offspring, because God is not a man.

No one but the Son of God looks into the hearts of creatures (Revelation 2:23), not believers, only He who is God (1:17-18). Believers, on the other hand, are sons of God only in the sense of being created, as in fathers 'creating' children. The Son of God is Son in the sense that He shares the NATURE of His Father, unlike believers, which his why he claimed to be (John 10:30-31), and was considered to have claimed to be (John 10:33, 36), and was believed to be (Clement, Polycarp, Ignatius, etc.), God, by the earliest Christians.

Comment: +1 for the first half as in "Abraham begat Isaac" etc. in Matthew 1:2 - the last three paragraphs are a different point

Comment: @controlvoice Have I removed all references or are there others?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check.

Answer (score 2):

### Monogenes in today's scholarship means 'only' based on  earliest biblical manuscripts in other languages

Following the scholarly research on the Greek word μονογενης, majority of modern translations had  μονογενης as expressing its original semantics based on its morphology: "only-one-of-its-kind" [μονος - one/only + γενος - kind/type]. Thus,

- μονογρνες υιος is "*the only-son-of-his-kind*" (i.e. the unique son or simply, the "only son" as found in the ASV)
- μονογενης θεος is "*the only-God-of-his-kind*" (i.e. the unique God or simply, the "only God" as found in the ESV)

Majority of the bible in other languages (Coptic, Latin, Syriac) in the 2nd-4th century CE had "only" for μονογενης. This follows the more ancient Hebrew *yachid* ("only") for μονογενης.

(source: God's Only Son: The Translation of John 3:16 in the Revised Standard Version, Dale Moody, 1953)

### Monogenes means 'only begotten' according to 2nd century church fathers

The Greek word *μονογενες* was deemed by second century Greek and Latin church fathers as "*only begotten*" **prior** to the Arian controversy in the fourth century.

- Irenaeus had the Latin "*unigenitus*" [A.D. 180] for *μονογενες* in John 1:18.
- Tertullian spoke of Christ as "*unigenitus because alone genitus of God*'' [Against Praxeas VII].
- The Greek fathers like Justin Martyr used *μονογενες* in the context of the begetting of the Son before all creatures (Dialogue to Trypho, 105).

### Monogenes (only) is synonymous with agapetos (beloved) in the Hebrew bible.

*Yachid* translates into Greek as μονογενης (monogenes) and αγαπητος (agapetos).

The "*life*" (soul) of a man in Psalm 22:21 (LXX) was literally his "only"[life]  (μονογενης). Thus, figuratively his [life] is *darling* for him. The sense is that he loves his life, knowing that he only lives once.

The figurative meaning "beloved" of μονογενης and its synonym αγαπητος was attested in the Septuagint.

### Isaac the only son (of Abraham and Sarah)

Isaac was the only begotten son of both Abraham *and Sarah*. The child of promise was Isaac alone and Isaac had one mother only, which logically means that he was the only begotten of his parents, who had him quite literally as their *only* son.

> 11 By faith even **Sarah herself received ability to conceive, even
> beyond the proper time of life**, since she considered Him faithful
> who had promised. 17 By faith **Abraham**, when he was tested, offered
> up **Isaac,** and he who had received the promises was offering up
> **his only begotten son**; (Hebrews 11:11, 11:17 NASB)

### Christians begotten of God (by faith)

> **every one who hath been begotten of God**, sin he doth not, because his seed in him doth remain, and he is not able to sin, because **of
> God he hath been begotten**.1 John 3:9 (Young's Literal Translation)

Christians were born of God when they accepted the name of the Son of God. But his new birth to become children of God *does not occur in eternity* (see John 1:12-13, 3:2-7).

### Jesus: the only *eternal* son

Jesus (as the pre-existent Word) was "The Son of God" because was begotten ***before all things were made.*** (i.e. eternally begotten).

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and **the
> Word was God**. 2 He was in the beginning with God. 3 **All things
> came into being through Him**, and apart from Him nothing came into
> being that has come into being. 18 No one has seen God at any time;
> **the only begotten God** who is in the bosom of the Father, He has explained Him. (John 1:1-3, 1:18 NASB).

**Summary**

In the second century CE, the Greek word μονογενης had two co-existing meanings: (i) "only begotten" according to the writings of the church fathers both in East and West and (ii) "only" in ancient bible translations in other languages (Coptic, Latin, Syriac) following the Hebrew *yachid* (only). Isaac was the *only son* [in both Hebrew and Greek MSS] of Abraham and Sarah in the book of Hebrews. Christians were not eternally begotten sons. Jesus was the only eternally begotten son. Thus, Jesus was the only *eternal* son.

**Conclusion**

- The literal definition of μονογενης  as "the only one of its kind" (or "only") , based on its morphology, is highly likely the original due to being attested in *pre-Christian* Hebrew and Greek manuscripts of the Old Testament.
- μονογενης as "*only*" is also the only consistent definition found in early biblical manuscripts in *all languages* (Greek, Hebrew, Syriac, Coptic, Latin) in the early church (circa 2nd-4th century CE).
- The figurative meaning "beloved" of μονογενης and its synonym αγαπητος was attested frequently in the Septuagint. Both μονογενης and αγαπητος translates the same Hebrew *yachid* (Literally, "*only*").
- The definition  'only begotten'  was already present as early as the second century CE. It was the universally accepted meaning by the church fathers both in the east and the west in regards to its application to Jesus Christ even before the Arian controversy.

Comment: the only begotten God... doesn't anyone see what an oxymoron that term is?  There might be a 'unique god', but we can't have two unique Gods! We already have, 'there is but one God, the Father', 1 Cor 8:6, Ehp 4:6, which plainly state the truth, and Jesus who speaks of His God, the Father. Go figure!

Comment: @user48152, The only begotten God , by virtue of being in *the bosom of the Father*, does not add up to two Gods when counted together with God the Father. They are still one God because they are one i.e. in unity, as **θεος** (God) (John 1:1, 10:30) and are both equal/greater/above (10:29) all the  **θεους** (gods)  (10:35 quoted by Jesus from Psalm 82:6a). You cannot have the Father and Jesus as two Gods when *they* possess *the same and one power.*

Comment: show me where this is so 'they possess the same and one power' Jesus life comes from the Father! John 1:1 says nothing about Jesus - nothing. 10:30 must be aligned with 17:11 to get the true meaning as opposed to the made-up one.

Comment: Jesus is not the only son of God.  Not only do John and Paul both speak of their communities as children of God, but genesis 6:2 and Job all speak of a group of the children of God.

Comment: @user48152 John 10:29 [the father is **greater than all**] John 10:30 [i and the father are **one**]. John 10:29 *must* be aligned with John 10:30. That's what you call *context*.

Comment: J 10:30 One what? and you still have a 'begotten' God with a God. None of this makes any biblical sense - are you ignoring 1 Cor 8:6, Ehp 4:6 because they don't fit the construct?

Comment: @user48152, it makes sense for a God to have a God over him if they are *different persons* but that does not mean that they are two different Gods. if they **are one** in greatness above all things **as God** (John 10:29-35), then, they are 'one God' in that sense.

Comment: (cont.) 1 Cor 8:6 (cf. Eph 4:6) had the Father as 'one God' (who is the *one Lord* of the Shema) and Jesus is the 'one Lord' (so that he was one God with the Father in that sense). According to scholars, Paul himself coined the new phrases *eis theos* and *eis kyrios* from Deut 6:4 LXX. Thus, if the Father alone is the one God, then, why did Jesus have the same name as the one God?

Comment: @Gus L. God has many sons but Jesus is the only *eternal* son (John 1:1-3, 1:18, 8:58, Gal 1:1, 1:11-12, 4:4).

Comment: @Radz, how are you certain that the other sons are not eternal?  And why is eternal a desirable thing?  Where is the history of the other sons of God that tells you they are not eternal?  What about lady wisdom in Proverbs?  She was there at the beginning of God’s way.  The first of his acquisitions.  Is she God’s child too?  Your claim about the other children of god being not eternal is simply unsupported.  Is this something important to you or just some hobby?  This is the truth of the universe mate.  Read close

Comment: @Gus L. All biblical evidence point to Jesus as the only *eternal* son. Christians were obviously not eternal for they were born here on earth without preexistence in the beginning as God.  The lady wisdom in Proverbs was personified as a child of God, begotten before the ages as also found in the Deuterocanon. What was ascribed to wisdom through personification (i.e. begetting before the ages) was a reality to the real person who is Christ. Only Christ was the son who was "*God*" and was there in the beginning "***before***  *all things were made*" (John 1:1-3, 3:16, Gal 1:1, 1:11-12, 4:4).

Comment: How do you exclude the sons of god in Genesis 6?  I am unaware of their backstory.  They also appear in Job

Comment: @GusL.They are the angels according to ancient Jewish texts (like the Dead Sea Scrolls and the LXX). Angels were created by God  and thus, they were not eternal.

Comment: Psalm 104:4-9 explicitly said that the angels were made in the passage. The spirits were made messengers [angels], and the flames of fire were made ministers. After making angels, God proceeded to make the land. In this case, the angels were created on the third day [Genesis 1:9-13]. This corresponds to Job 38:4-8 wherein the morning stars and all the sons of God sang and shouted for joy when God laid the foundation of the earth (land). The term “earth” in biblical language usually refers to the dry land, not the globe.

Comment: ....  there is a Hebrew word for Angel and it is not used interchangeably with “Son of God.”  Also, the hebrew doesn’t say that wisdom was created in proverbs 8.  It says that God “acquired or possessed by or grasped” it at the beginning of his way.  It is actually from the same verb from which Cain’s name is derived in Genesis 4.  It is certainly not of the form “created” or “made.”  There is no implication that wisdom was created anywhere... this seems relevant given the related greek word Logos to Sophia.

Comment: Also, “the star of the morning” is  Nebuchadnezzar, not a son of Yahweh.  That is a flat read of Isaiah 14 and the references to Babylonian captivity.  That king fell from on high when Cyrus (God’s Messiah) smashed through mesopotamia.

Answer (score 2):

The best meaning according to usage of μονογενής is *only* or *unique*.  However, there isn't complete agreement over it never meaning *only begotten,* while sometimes translating it *only begotten* doesn't make sense.

Logos Bible Software indicates that μονογενής only has the sense of *unique* in the New Testament.

**Figure 1.** Senses of μονογενής in the New Testament.
[image]

Is this just a new concept from modern times?  OK, what Hebrew word does μονογενής translate in the Septuagint (LXX); predates the New Testament, but similar language.

**Figure 2.** Hebrew word does μονογενής translate in the Septuagint (LXX).
[image]

μονογενής translates one Hebrew word יָחִיד. Thus, no sense of *only begotten.*

**Figure 3.** Senses of יָחִיד in the MT.
[image]

> יָחִיד ... adj. and subst. *only, only one, solitary* ... — 1. *only one*, especially of an only son, Gn 22:2 [isaac], 12, 16 את בנך את יְחִידְךָ thy son, thine only one, אֵבֶל יָחִיד Am 8:10 Je 6:26 mourning for an only son, כמספד על היחיד Zc 12:10, Pr 4:3 רַךְ וְיָחִיד לפני אמי; so fem. יְחִידָה Ju 11:34. 2. fem. יְחִידָה as subst. ψ 22:21; 35:17 יְחִידָתִי my *only* one, poet. for my life, as the one unique and priceless possession which can never be replaced (in each || נַפְשִׁי). 3. *solitary*, ψ 25:16 כי יחיד ועני אני; 68:7 מוֹשִׁיב יְחִידִים בַּיְתָה causing solitary, isolated ones
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). *In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 402). Clarendon Press.

Things to consider in Daniel Wallaces grammar:

```
        Root Fallacy
```

> As lexicographers have long noted, the root meaning of a word is not necessarily an accurate guide to the meaning of the word in later literature. The same is true of morpho-syntactic categories: One ought not look for some kind of invariant meaning that is always present with the preposition. The meaning of words changes in time. Further, a word has a field of meaning rather than a point. Such is no less true for prepositions than for other words.
> --
> Wallace, D. B. (1996). *Greek Grammar beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament* (p. 363). Zondervan.

> Linguists have long noted the etymological fallacy when it comes to word meanings.
> --
> Wallace, D. B. (1996). *Greek Grammar beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament* (p. 511). Zondervan.

Lexical meanings of γένος.

> γένος, ους, τό (...) *race, stock*. 1. *descendants* of a common ancestor ... 2. *family, relatives* ... 3. *nation, people* ... 4. *class, kind* ... -- Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 156). University of Chicago Press.

Technically Isaac wasn't Abraham's only begotten son, but he was his only heir.

> Πίστει προσενήνοχεν ⸂Ἀβραὰμ τὸν Ἰσαὰκ πειραζόμενος⸃ καὶ τὸν μονογενῆ προσέφερεν,*
> (Heb. 11:17, NA28)

> Suffix
> -γενής • (-genḗs) m or f (neuter -γενές); third declension
> (forming adjectives) *born in a certain place or condition*
> ‎ἔνδον (éndon) + ‎-γενής (-genḗs) → ‎ἐνδογενής (endogenḗs)
> ‎οἶκος (oîkos) + ‎-γενής (-genḗs) → ‎οἰκογενής (oikogenḗs)
> (forming adjectives) **of a kind**
> ‎ἕτερος (héteros) + ‎-γενής (-genḗs) → ‎ἑτερογενής (heterogenḗs)
> ‎ὁμός (homós) + ‎-γενής (-genḗs) → ‎ὁμογενής (homogenḗs)
> ‎μόνος (mónos) + ‎-γενής (-genḗs) → ‎μονογενής (monogenḗs)
> -- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%AE%CF%82

Comment: So you conclude that the best meaning of the word μονογενής is **unique**? Could you, please write a conclusion, concluding **unique* as the best translation?

Comment: @Salah It's done. Added to beginning.

Comment: I prefer adding a conclusion to the post before editing. Conclusion, i.e: at the end of the post you write a side title: **Conclusion** then, write the conclusion. I prefer the post before editing.

Comment: Do mean Senses by Sinses?

Comment: thank's I'll fix.  Looks like you already did.

Comment: You might be interested in this other question on this verse.  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60096/john-316-might-%ce%bf%e1%bd%95%cf%84%cf%89%cf%82-be-a-reference-to-moses/60124#60124

Comment: According to the BAGD lexicon γένος can mean *class* or *kind*.   It does not necessarily mean *begotten*. See addition added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A problem with the verse if it just says that Jesus is God's only Son, is that ***God has many sons, not just one.*** "...and all the sons of God shouted for joy" at creation (Job 38:7). That was before the first human son of God was created, bear in mind. Adam was called a son of God too (Luke 3:38). And God is "bringing many sons to glory" (Hebrews 2:10).

It should therefore come as no surprise to anyone who noted John's first 14 verses in his gospel, all about Jesus' pre-human existence, that when it comes to the sonship of Jesus Christ, the Word of God, it is a unique sonship.

All sons of God have been created by God - angels and humans - but the Word of God, who was with God in the beginning (i.e. before creation started) and who is God and who became flesh and walked amongst John and the other disciples, is uniquely the only-begotten Son. That term means not-created, unlike all other sons, who are all created. Those opening verses in John's gospel should have prepared us for the verse you quote. Verse 3 shows that this Word made everything that was made, logically proving that he could not have been made himself.

In conclusion, all ancient biblical manuscripts have the same Greek wording here, but it is various translations that give rise to the differences.  What is unreliable is translation that uses accepted Greek text wording that *can* have a variety of meanings, to result in statements that don't agree with clear statements about the unique status of the Son of God elsewhere. Of course, those who do not believe the Bible to be the inspired word of God would disagree, but that's another issue. Translations that read "only-begotten Son" are authentic and reliable and the Greek words allow for that. Those in favour of translations that do not put it that way would claim their translation is also allowable, and therefore authentic and reliable. Yet only in near-on the past 200 years have different translations arisen, which detract from the unique sense of Christ's sonship. The problem remains, however, that **both schools of translation of this verse make different theological points, which is why the broader biblical context must be taken into account, as the PO asks for**, not least the fact that God has many 'sons', not just one, and John's first 14 verses ought to have prepared us for his unique presentation of Christ to have remained consistent in 3:16.

Comment: Tone is a bit snarky, frankly. (Second paragraph)

Comment: @barbecue  I'm a bit surprised that such a mild statement seems to create such a reaction. If course, if you don't believe Jesus had a pre-human existence, you won't like my second paragraph.  Do accept my apologies, if that is the case - nothing snide was intended.

Comment: @Anne The statement "It should therefore come as no surprise to anyone who has a clue about Jesus' pre-human existence." assumes a premise and draws a conclusion, which is fine, but the wording implies that those who reject the premise are "clueless." Also, "What is unreliable is translation that in any way seeks to lower Christ..." implies that any translation that excludes begotten is in fact trying to do that. This implies bad faith on the part of translators who don't include begotten. I'm not offended personally, I just wanted to point out a possible issue with acceptance of your answer.

Comment: @barbecue You make further valid points, so I have taken out the phrases in question, and replaced them. I trust this will remove any idea of ‘bad faith’, which certainly was not my idea, but if that seemed implied, must be removed. I’m glad that you have given me constructive directions on this, and trust you, and yours, will have a peaceful and safe new year.

Comment: nice improvements!