# What does it mean that Jesus is the ''only Son''?

Tags: jesus, christology, bible-versions

Jesus was the ''only Son'' of God according to many English bible translations (John 3:16, 1 John 4:9, *monogenes uios* ESV, NLT, CEV, GNT, HCSB, ASV, NETBible etc.).

- What does it mean that Jesus is the ''only Son'' [of God]?

i think this has never been asked before.  i am seeking answer that explains what does the phrase ''son of God'' mean in the bible, and given that God has other sons (Job 1:6, Luke 3:38, 1 John 3:1, 3:9), how does the sonship of Jesus differ to the point of being identified as ''the only Son'' [of God]?

Comment: Related (and, I would say answered) [John 3:16 'Only Begotten'](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/51140/john-316-greek-only-begotten/51143#51143) There are a number of other questions which deal with the word _monogenes_ as it is a big subject. There are many 'sons of God' by creation (see Job) and there are many 'sons of God' by redemption and new birth (see the epistles). But there is only one who is _monogenes_.

Comment: Are you asking why the author(s) of John's Gospel rejected both God's figurative firstborn son Yisrael (יִשְׂרָאֵֽל) declared in Exodus 4:22 & God's figurative begotten son Shlomoh (שְׁלֹמֹֽה) declared in [2 Samuel 7:14 + 1 Chronicles 17:13]  **by claiming God had "only [one] son" in John 3:16**?

Comment: Please clarify how this question is different from others on the same topic.