# John 3:16 "... only begotten son...", "... only son..." which is more authentic and reliable?

Tags: john, christology

John 3:16 DRB;

> 16 For God so loved the world, as to give his **only begotten Son**; that whosoever believeth in him, may not perish, but may have life everlasting.

John 3:16 ESV;

> 16 “For God so loved the world,[a] that he gave his **only Son**, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.

There are many translations which mention "**begotten**", many other which didn't mention "**begotten**", so what is the Greek textual basis?, Which more authentic and reliable? Especially, where this passage is used in many Christian Creeds.